# Insert new line in mail template override

Tags: plone, plone-4.x

In email templates like this: https://github.com/plone/Products.PasswordResetTool/blob/master/Products/PasswordResetTool/skins/PasswordReset/mail_password_template.pt

how to add new lines in my customized text?

I'm trying to say:

```
Hello

Some text
```

and the result is:

```
Hello Some text
```

I think it is related to `Content-Type: text/plain`.

UPDATE:

Tried:

```
aaa \n
aaa

bbb \r\n\r\n
bbb

ccc <br>
ccc

ddd <br />
ddd

eee


eeee
```

The result is a single line:

```
aaa \n aaa bbb \r\n\r\n bbb ccc <br> ccc ddd <br /> ddd eee eeee
```

Comment: Cannot confirm a problem. When customizing the template and inserting a linebreak with the return-key, and then some more text, it'll be sended including the linebreak (Plone-4.3.17).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After simplifying the template it works without any special tricks.

```
<tal:root define="lt string:&lt;;gt string:&gt;;
                  member python:options['member'];
                  portal_state context/@@plone_portal_state;
                  view context/@@passwordreset_view;
                  isAnon context/@@plone_portal_state/anonymous;
                  reset python:options['reset']"
>From: <span tal:replace="structure view/encoded_mail_sender" />
To: <span tal:replace="python:member.getProperty('email')" />
Subject: Request to reset your password
Content-Type: text/plain
Precedence: bulk

Hello

Some text

More text

Kind regards
Organization Name
</tal:root>
```

return the text as I need it:

```
Hello

Some text

More text

Kind regards
Organization Name
```